# How is the Image Asset Studio reached in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-icons

I am using Android Studio 2022.2.1 Patch 2 and I would like to access the 'Image Asset Studio' [IAS] (if it still exists).

The directions I have for accessing the IAS are to open the project's 'android' folder, locate the 'res' folder, right-click the 'res' folder, and then an option for accessing the IAS would then appear.

[image]

The image shows what I see when following the said directions.

Since the instructions above do not lead to the IAS, could you suggest an alternative set of directions towards the IAS please?

Answer (score 1):

I Google searched and saw a StackOverflow thread with a solution which was to do the following:

1. With the relevant project open, from Android Studio's File tab, choose "Open ..." and select the 'android' folder, and have it open in a new window.
2. Wait for the various loading/synchronising to be completed.
3. Locate the 'res' folder and right-click on it.  Hover to 'New' and now the 'Image Asset' option will be available.

[image]

In the Google search I completed there was a 63 second YouTube video in the results.  I watched that and then I realised that the StackOverflow response was accurate.

Now resolved.

Comment: Yes, my issue was that I needed to wait for gradle to sync and for Android Studio to index all files before the option was available.